# Can't update rails has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try:

```
@item.associations.update_attributes(:tag_id=>params[:tag])
```

and

```
@item.associations.tag_id=params[:tag]
```

Both give me undefined method errors for update_attributes and tag_id=, respectively. Here's my setup:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations,:foreign_key=>"item_id",:dependent=>:destroy
  has_many :reverse_associations,:foreign_key=>"tag_id",:class_name=>"Association"
  has_many :tags,:through=>:associations
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations,:foreign_key=>"tag_id",:dependent=>:destroy
  has_many :reverse_associations,:foreign_key=>"item_id",:class_name=>"Association"
  has_many :items,:through=>:associations
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to update `tag_id` on the entire `@item.associations` collection instead of updating a single `Assocation` instance.

The proper way to solve this depends on what you're trying to accomplish. To update the `tag_id` for all associations in `@item.association`, try:

```
@item.associations.each do |association|
  association.update_attributes(:tag_id => params[:tag])
end
```

If you want to update the tag id for a specific `Association`, then you somehow need to get that association first:

```
# Just picking the first association for the item as an example.
# You should make sure to retrieve the association that you actually
# want to update.
retagged_association = @item.associations.first

# Now, retag the association
retagged_association.update_attributes(:tag_id => params[:tag])
```

Comment: oh. "duh" moment for me... right now there's only one association for the item, so i guess this didn't occur to me.

Comment: of course, now i just realized that updating an association isn't even necessary, i can just create/destroy as needed.